# Solve for $x$ in $3^x=5^2$ by logarithm.

Tags: logarithms

Was solving using properties of logarithm but got stuck at the equation $x\log 3=\log5+\log5$

Comment: So you have $x(a)=2b$ and you have to solve for $x$.

Comment: Yes dont know the answer

Comment: If that's a minus sign on left need to adjust solution.

Comment: Ask yourself,how would you solve for $x$ in $5x=7$?

Comment: We can simply write $x=\log_3(5^2)$ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a side note to the previous answers, $x = \frac{2\log 5}{\log 3}$ can be further simplified in the denominator to $x = \frac{\log 25}{\log 3}$, and using log rules $x = \log_3{25}$. This is a way to remove the fraction.

-FruDe

Comment: Thank u for sol

Comment: Sure thing @Maths

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\log 3$ and $\log 5$ in your equation are just constants. How would you solve for $x$ if they were replaced by say, $1$ and $2$?

Comment: Thanks a lot paulino for helping

Answer (score 0):

you are almost done
$$x\log3=\log5+\log5=2\log5$$
$$x=\frac{2\log5}{\log3}$$
$$x=\frac{2\cdot 0.6989}{0.4771}\approx2.93$$

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score -1):

$$3^x=5^2\implies \log3^x=\log5^2\implies x\log3=2\log5\implies x=\frac{2\log5}{\log3}$$
I hope that helps :)